# Get custom datetime format from standard format

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

In my script, I receive a standard format like "D", "f", "R" or others. This is a Standard DateTime Format, according to MSDN.

Taking into account the current culture of the user, I would like to get the custom format of this standard format.

Example, let's say my user is from France (fr-FR) :

"d" = "dd/MM/yyyy"

"D" = "dddd d MMMM yyyy"

"F" = "dddd d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a `char` version of that format, but then you could do it like this:

```
CultureInfo culture = //get your culture
var patterns = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns(yourFormatChar);
```

Comment: Simple and clean! It works like a charm! And I guess that I always take the first element since GetAllDateTimePatterns() returns a string[]?.

Comment: @NLemay It depends if you want the others, I think some format strings return more than one. However I'd assume taking the first element is safe.

Comment: Ok! Not sure to understand in what kind of case I can get more than one custom format for a unique standard format. How does C# would handle this when using DateTime.toString()? But anyway, the first is probably the good one!

Comment: @NLemay I honestly don't know, I'll do some testing and I'll be back.

Comment: @NLemay LINQPad says that the ones that can return more results are d, D, f, F, g, G, t, T, and U. (at least in en-UK). However, the first ones are the most common for all of them, so I'd take the first, always.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code do get the patterns:

```
var c = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
Console.WriteLine(c.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern);
Console.WriteLine(c.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
Console.WriteLine(c.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern);
```

The result from a console app is the following

```
dddd d MMMM yyyy
dd/MM/yyyy
dddd d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: he needs it for format strings.

Comment: This example makes him able to get the format, he just need to adapt the code for his use.

Comment: Than you for your time. But like I said yo Tim S. and D Stanley, I was looking for a simpler solution (with less code as possible). Sorry, my question could have been more clear.

Comment: Yes, I agree It'sNotALie's answer is better than mine and the others. See ya

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTimeFormatInfo dtf = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
switch (standardFormat)
{
    case "d":
        return dtf.ShortDatePattern;
    case "D":
        return dtf.LongDatePattern;
    case "F":
        return dtf.FullDateTimePattern;
    // add other standard formatters
    default:
        throw new ArgumentException("Say what?", "standardFormat");
}
```

The [standard formatter documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) says what properties you will need to look for.

Comment: This works (improvement from the other answer) but would be a pain to write, debug and mantain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought about this solution, but I'm looking for a cleaner way to do this. Like It'sNotALie says, this code is a pain to maintain. Sorry for not being enough clear in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Use the various properties of the `DateTimeFormat` of the current thread (or the UI Thread, whichever is appropriate):

```
"d" = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern 

"D" = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern 

"F" = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern
```

Comment: @It'sNotALie. In what way?  Those three properties represent the standard format strings for "d", "D", and "F" respectively - it even says so in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern.aspx).

Comment: Yes, but for extra format strings it would be a pain. And if you typoed it, you need to open the internet, go to the docs, hunt for the right one, fix your code. And then do it again for any others.

Comment: I agree with It'sNotALie. I prefer to let C# handle this job, and don't add so much code to my app if I can. But still, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Some reflection might ensure, that you'll get the same expanded format strings that are used internally:

```
string GetRealFormat(string format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi)
{
    MethodInfo method = Type.GetType("System.DateTimeFormat")
        .GetMethod("GetRealFormat", 
                   BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    return method.Invoke(null, new object[] { format, dtfi }) as string;
}
```

```
string format = GetRealFormat("d", DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo) // dd.MM.yyyy
```

Comment: If I understand well, with this solution, I'm sure to get the best match instead of a string[]? This is not the simplest, but surely a neat and nice answer! Thank you!

Comment: This solution does not work in .netstandart:
Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.ReadOnlySpan`1[System.Char]